# Is it possible to enforce a return type with an interface using python ABC?

Tags: python, oop, interface, abc

Say I have the following code sample. I want the 'walk' function to return a dictionary for all animals, I am using the interface to enforce this. However, below code sample will run just fine. Is it possible to modify the interface so that it enforces a return type of dict (not allowing me to run this code sample)?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def walk(self) -> dict:
        return dict
    
    
class Cat(Animal):
    def walk(self) -> None:
        print("Walking")
        
        
cat = Cat()
position = cat.walk()
```

Comment: ABCs don't care about types at all. You could define `walk = 3` in the definition of `Cat` rather than define a method, and you could instantiate the class. (`cat.walk()` would raise the obvious TypeError indicating that an `int` object is not callable, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: `mypy`, however, will catch the attempt to change the return type of the inherited method, even if it is *not* an abstract method. (It will also catch your attempt here to return `dict` rather than an instance of `dict`.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I have a specific use case where the return type is quite important and I would prefer to enforce it to minimize future mistakes. I'll think of something else.